# Skip Exception Firebase Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to register 100s of users to firebase via loop (JS) with given list of emails and passwords.

But few of them are already exist and few's email is badly formatted. So the script i have wrote throw exception if **user email already registered or is badly formatted**. I want to skip that user's registration and continue to next one.

How to skip in loop if exception happens.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
//Variables of email and password
 if (email !== '' && email !== undefined) {
        const promise = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(function(response) {
           console.log(response.uid);
     });
     promise.catch(function(e){
        console.log(e.message);
        //Skip and continue to next iteration
     });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all:

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  promises.push(firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function(userRecord) {
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error).
    }));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
  console.log('done');
});
```